# Meteor Cordova Offline issue

Tags: cordova, meteor, grounddb

I am trying to make my Meteor App (angular-meteor) offline capable with GroundDB.
But when I start the App without Internet Connection I get the message:

`Possible issue: deviceready did not fire in a reasonable amount of time. This can be caused by plugins in an inconsistent state. One possible solution: uninstall/remove all plugins and reinstall them. Additionally, one or more plugins might be faulty or out of date`

I already searched the Internet without any success, only thing I find is:
https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/259

I tried to remove Cordova-Plugins, one at a time and all at once, still no deviceready.

What else could be the cause?

Comment: any resolution? I am running into the same issue.

Comment: Switched to React Native due to this and other problems in Meteor-Angular.